# Kendo UI DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui.But datepicker doesnot work when clicking on the input field the datepicker doesnot appear. Please clarify me how to call kendo datepicker() in my .aspx page.
  **My code is**

```
<script src="Js/jquery1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="Js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="CSS/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CSS/kendo.web.js"></script>
<script src="CSS/console.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#date").kendoDatePicker();
    });
</script>     
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div  style="width: 155px;">
            <input id="date" />
        </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: You have all ready one answer to the question, and you totally change it ! Maybe consider accept the answer that solve your first question, and then make a new one.

Comment: I have got answer to my first question.Now i want to bind the selected date to a asp .net label

Comment: If you get answer, then accept it, not change the question, and make a new one question. If you change the question people that come here can not understand what the answer talk about because it is on the question that you try to totally change.

Comment: Remove all other javascript and css reference, other than from kendo and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I noticed that you are loading kendo.web.js and kendo.all.js, which is incorrect. Choose one of these scripts and also load the CSS file. [Check the related docs.](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/downloading-kendo) [Here is a working jsBin demo.](http://jsbin.com/enewos/3)

Answer (score 0):

You must have a input field inside your form.

```
 <input id="date">
```

And then in the script use the following

```
$("#date").kendoDatePicker();
```

Comment: Sorry I did not scroll down. Then you did it right. It is only your scripts not included correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<script src="CSS/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CSS/kendo.web.js"></script>
<script src="CSS/console.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/console.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You don't need kendo.web.js.
I assume that you don't have your JavaScript files in your CSS directory.